# Show the equi-integrability of a finite set of $\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$-functions

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, uniform-integrability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu$ be a measure space.

> > A set $\mathcal{F}$ of measurable, numerical functions is called *equi-integrable* if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ it exists a nonnegative, integrable function $h$ such that
> >     $$
> > \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int 1_{\left\{\lvert f\rvert\geq h\right\}}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu < \varepsilon.
> > $$

Now the task is to show the following:

> > $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ finite $\implies \mathcal{F}$ equi-integrable.

My idea to prove that is:

Let $\mathcal{F}=\left\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\right\}$ with $f_i\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. This means that $0\leq\lvert f_i\rvert=m_i<\infty$ a.s. for $i=1,\ldots.n$. Choose
$$
h:=\max_{i\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}}\left\{m_i\right\}.
$$
Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $f_i\in\mathcal{F}$ it is
$$
\int 1_{\left\{\lvert f_i\rvert\geq h\right\}}\lvert f_i\rvert\, d\mu=0<\varepsilon
$$
and because this was not dependent on $i$, it is for any $\varepsilon >0$
$$
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int 1_{\left\{\lvert f\rvert\geq h\right\}}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu=0<\infty.
$$

So $\mathcal{F}$ is equi-integrable.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: Apparently not. Anyway, bad manners.

Answer (score 4):

Try $h=2\sum\limits_{f\in\mathcal F}|f|$. Let $A=\bigcap\limits_{f\in\mathcal F}\{f=0\}$. Then, for every $f$ in $\mathcal F$, $\{|f|\geqslant h\}=A$ and $\int\limits_A|f|\mathrm d\mu=0$.

Additionally, note that the argument based on the fact that for every $f$ in $\mathcal L^1_\mu$ there would exist some finite constant $c$ such that $|f|\leqslant c$ almost surely, is wrong (try $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$ with $\mathcal A$ the Borel sigma-algebra and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: This is only the case for measurable, non-negative functions, right?

Comment: Nonnegative: no. Measurable: yes, but anyway, $\mathcal F$ is made of measurable functions, isn't it?

Comment: In our reading we had: Let $f$ be a non-negative, measurable, numerical function then: $\int f\, d\mu<\infty\implies f<\infty$ a.s..

Comment: Sure, but being almost surely finite and being bounded are not the same condition. Did you read the example in my post?

Comment: Sorry, I do not chat.

Comment: We had the following statement: $\mathcal{F}$ equi-integrable $\Leftrightarrow \left\{\lvert f\rvert: f\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$ is equi-integrable. So I can show that for $\mathcal{F}:=\left\{f_i: f_i\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1, i=1,\ldots,n\right\}$ the set $\left\{\lvert f_i\rvert: f_i\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$ is equi-integrable. This are non-negative, integrable, measurable functions, so that means that $\lvert f_i\rvert < \infty$ a.s., what means to me that outside a nullset $N_i$ it is $\lvert f_i(\omega)\rvert\leq\sup_{w\in N^C}\lvert f_i(w)\rvert=:m_i<\infty$.

Comment: So to my opinion, $\left\{\omega: \lvert f_i\rvert\geq h\right\}$ ($h$ as in my thread) is a nullset.

Comment: PLEASE READ the example in my post.

Comment: Do not see why you definied $A$ there... resp. why $A=\left\{\lvert f\rvert\geq h\right\}$ and why this is the empty set.